# Multiple drop targets react-dropzone

Tags: reactjs, react-dropzone

Basically I want to have multiple `<input/>` inside one dropzone.

[image: should look something like this]

It would look something like that.
All the drop targets should enable their `isDragActive` when entering the parent panel.

Is this at all possible with react-dropzone?

Answer (score 0):

Just pass more `<input's />` as childs to Dropzone like:

```js
<Dropzone
  onDrop={(onDropProps) =>
    console.log("onDropProps in onDrop event handler", onDropProps)
  }
  accept='image/jpg,image/jpeg,image/png'
  multiple={true}
>
  {({ getRootProps, getInputProps, isDragActive }) => {
    console.log("getRootProps", getRootProps());
    console.log("getInputProps", getInputProps());
    console.log("isDragActive", isDragActive);
    return (
      <div>
        <div {...getRootProps()}>
          <input {...getInputProps()} />
          {<p className='fileDrop'>Try dropping one or more files here</p>}
        </div>

        <div {...getRootProps()}>
          <input {...getInputProps()} />
          {<p className='fileDrop'>Try dropping one or more files here</p>}
        </div>

        <div {...getRootProps()}>
          <input {...getInputProps()} />
          {<p className='fileDrop'>Try dropping one or more files here</p>}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }}
</Dropzone>
```

I am using Dropzone on a collapsable table, so when I collapse a row I'll get access to all three props like

[image]

Comment: This doesn't allow the inner drop targets to activate when entering their parent though, and when I put the root props on the parent div, that becomes a drop (and click) target.